# Why does OnTabSelected get called after adding a fragment via FragmentTransaction

Tags: android, fragmenttransaction

So I have this code :

```
public void openSearch() {
        FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if(mSearchFragment == null) {
                    mSearchFragment = SearchFragment.newInstance("Search");
                    t.add(android.R.id.content,mSearchFragment);
        } else {t.show(mSearchFragment); }
        t.commit();
}
```

I call openSearch from here:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        boolean returnValue = false;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            openSearch();
        } 
    }
```

after openSearch() runs.. onTabSelected is called immediately after.  Why is this?

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction ft) {
```

If you need mroe information please let me know. I included only the pieces I thought were relevant to lessen the chatter.    What's even crazier is that the first time I run this onTabSelected gets selected, but if i navigate my app and run openSearch again the 2nd and consecutive times the onOptionsItemSelected won't be called. it's only the initial time

Edit:
This is the main content view and I'm just supplying fragments for the viewPager. The Layouts for each fragment is the same, a FrameLayout with one LinearLayout child.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/search_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the search view" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Could you describe your layout? A layout file or screenshot with an explanation should suffice.